# How to get this window layout in WPF?

Tags: wpf, layout, window

im trying to create a Window with the following layout:

[Layout http://www.x-toolz.com/downloads/layout.jpg](http://www.x-toolz.com/downloads/layout.jpg)

As you can see the window has 3 rows (15*, 70*, 15*) and 3 columns (same).

How can I redesign a rectangle to fit the geometry of the corners?
If it can't be done with rectangles i would need another control that I can place content (Grid, StackPanel) in.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

MemphiZ

Comment: Which of those shapes need to have content in them?

Comment: Is the window inside the octogon and how do you want the contents layed out?

Comment: agent-j: All of them :) I would like to have a Grid in all 9 shapes.

Comment: Bob Vale: Im sorry, I don't understand your question. The whole thing is in the window, basically is the window...

Comment: @MemphiZ you answered half my question to agent-j, What about the contents of the grid section, are they clipped, rotated on scaled?

Comment: The whole thing will be an overlay to my desktop on the second monitor. Every shape will contain a Grid or UserControl displaying Information or Shortcuts (Buttons). What do you mean with clipped, rotated or scaled exactly?

Comment: WPF Doesn't allow you to easily perform overflow/text wrapping around a non rectangular shape, however you can CLIP the contents so overflow is blanked out using a polygon and an opacity mask

Comment: Bob Vale: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Blue">
        <!-- Top Left Content Goes Here -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="Aqua">
        <!-- Top Middle Content Goes Here-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Gold">
        <!-- Top Right Content Goes Here -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="Magenta">
        <!-- Middle LEft Content goes here -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Background="Lime">
        <!-- Middle Right Content goes here -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Red">
        <!-- Bottom Left Content Goes Here -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Background="DarkGoldenrod">
        <!-- Bottom Middle Content Goes Here-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Silver">
        <!-- Bottom Right Content Goes Here -->
    </Grid>
    <!-- This is used to shape the center" -->
    <Polygon x:Name="main" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="White" Points="0,15 15,0 55,0 70,15 70,55 55,70 15,70 0,55" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0"/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Pink" >
        <Grid.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=main}" />
        </Grid.OpacityMask>
        <!-- Centre Content Goes Here-->
    </Grid>

    </Grid>


</Grid>
</Window>
```

This produces this layout.  The limitation is that WPF does its bounds clipping to rectangles so any content that overflows the regions will be made invisible (i.e. Clipped).

You could partially work around this by applying padding to each grid element to a create a rectangular area that fits inside each region.

[image: Example]

Comment: I've selected this as answer as its easier to implement and the shapes have not to be created for each corner. Awesome Thanks!

Comment: One Problem though: If I set the Poligons Fill to Transparent it looks strange. Any Idea how to fix this? I would like to have my desktop coming through there...

Answer (score 5):

You could do that with a grid with 9 cells.  Create 8 usercontrols to hold your outside content.  If you want it size adjustable, you are going to have to work a little magic.

Each corner user control would have a 2x2 grid and for the upper left panel I will give a small example.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="TopLeft"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Path Grid.Column="1" Data="M0.5,0.5 L239.5,0.5 120,120 0.5,239.5 z" Fill="Black" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the above example a 2 x 2 grid, with a diagonal path in the bottom right.  If your main window is going to resize you will have to decide whether or not your border areas will resize accordingly or be a static frame around the body of the window.

Here is the window:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MegaPanel"
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:TopLeft Margin="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I failed to put a Content presenter in the UserControl, but you would put that in there to add content to it.

The body area of the window would have to be handled with some care.  You can set the Margin to negative values to allow the contents of the body to spill out into the frame areas.

[image: Here is what the Top and Left Side look like.]

## Edit

Example:

```
<local:TopLeft Margin="0">
    <local:TopLeft.Tag>
        <ListBox/>
    </local:TopLeft.Tag>
</local:TopLeft>
```

The above change to Top left assigns the ListBox to the Tag property of the TopLeft usercontrol.  In the User control, I bound the ContentPresenter to the Tag Property of the UserControl.  ListBox is assigned to the tag, ContentPresenter gets the ListBox from the Tag.  Of you can regester custom properties in the UserControl codebehind if you want things in several areas.

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,125,125" Content="{Binding Tag, ElementName=UserControl}"/>
```

For registering custom DependencyProperties check [**this post**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/bfb5759f-699b-45d2-8221-26792b9eb809) out.

Comment: Thats a very good start! Im trying to add the ContentPresenter but unfortunately I can't get it to work. If I add a ContentPresenter to the UserControl and then set <local:TopLeft.Content> in the window the content is being display but the black stuff is gone... Can you show me how to add the ContentPresenter correctly?

Comment: What kind of content are you adding?  Does it have a background color?  If so, make it transparent or partially so.  Really the content presenter would sit in the UserControls root grid panel.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It worked but Bob Vale's answer is easier to implement, please check my comment on his answer. Thank you very much anyway!