# How to integrate Visual Studio in my Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF application which is tiled into multiple parts as you can see
[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949004/how-to-get-this-window-layout-in-wpf)

In the middle part I have a Grid where I would like to place Visual Studio in.
I've checked the method "TranslatePoint" and the WinAPI call "WinMove". With them I would be able to move the Visual Studio window in place. By setting the Grid to HitTestVisible=False I would also be able to write and click in the window.
The Problem I have is that my VS environment is set up for dual monitors and I would need it to fit in that Grid. Resetting VS's settings and importing a settings file on each start of VS would be painfull (but could be done using devenv.exe /ResetSettings SettsingsFile).

Does anyone know a better way of having VS in my application?

Comment: This is a very special question.  Be sure to look at the link too.

Comment: @Memphiz: The one in the question (top right)

Comment: +1 for the best question today, you made my day. Although I think that it's going to be closed :(

Comment: Why would it be closed? Reason: Impossible?

Comment: No, right now there are 3 votes because it's deemed "Too localized". In other words, the problem is seen as too specific to be of use to others. Maybe there's a way to broaden the scope...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into using the Visual Studio Shell to create your application with Visual Studio as the basis. You're not goingt to really be able to embed the Visual Studio application into your application.

The [IronPython Studio project](http://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/) is an open source example of using the Visual Studio Shell.