# How can I overlay a triangle shaped graphic on the upper left of a WPF window?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to figure out how to have a UI design on my main window application that looks like this:

[image]

The base object is a DockPanel - I know I can set the DockPanel background to set a graphic there, but the Top Dock area always covers the triangle area of the background. I can't figure out how to set the top Dock area that contains the buttons to "hide" behind the triangle graphic. Does anybody know of a good technique to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending CodeWarrior answer, put the DockPanel inside a grid, and the triangle as another child of the grid with higher z index, you can use rows and cols or just use vertical and horizontal alignment.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Simple to implement without changing the structure already present in my application. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a grid with a row to contain your buttonbar at the top and a column to constrain the triangular element.  Personally I would make the triangular area and the buttonbar separate controls.

Take a look at this answer I made a few month back on a different question with a similar end result:
[How to get this window layout in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949004/how-to-get-this-window-layout-in-wpf/6949525#6949525)

Comment: Thanks CodeWarrior. Nice technique, but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted to before I saw Chen's answer, which was much easier to implement with my application's current structure.

Comment: Any ideas on how to generate the dropshadow effect for the triangle edge?

Comment: The bottom right - you can sort of see the shadow in the screenshot I posted.