# How to make a layout in WPF (overlay uniformgrid?)

Tags: wpf, layout

I am trying to create a window with the given layout and I am curious about the best way to do it. I have set the window background to be a tiled image of the lighter color. I then thought I would add a uniformgrid with five columns and one row with the 5th column having an "orange" slightly transparent background. Then I would add another uniform grid with 5 rows and 1 column with rows 2 & 3 with the same "orange" color settings.  Eventually I will add a company logo to the top left corner and some text in the horizontal band of "orange". My methods do not seem to be working :-( any guidance as I am looking into this myself would be much appreciated. [image: example]

Comment: why not a 2x3 grid? you can use `Width="5*"` and `Width="1*"`

Comment: Yes that could work . . . then I would manually set the color of the intersecting cells.

Comment: I have previously used a grid with rows/columns dimensions set to star values, populated with user controls to hold the content. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949004/how-to-get-this-window-layout-in-wpf/6949525#6949525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer was just to use a grid and set the background color of the cells to be my chosen color with a slight transparency. I could then either set the cells of intersection to a darker color or add a label to the intersecting cells with the same background and transparency. Thank you every one for your help. Over the past hour I have learned a lot about xaml and WPF.

Answer (score 2):

This works well for me:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Yellow">
            <Image Source="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Orange"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Orange"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Yellow"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="Orange"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
            I am nice text spanning the whole row! Look, here's a lot
            of me in the cell.
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If you insist on the half-transparent stripes, you can make something like

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
      Background="Orange" Opacity="0.5"/>
```

or

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Background="#80FF7F00"/>
```

(included opacity into the color) etc.

For example, try this (you'll need to tweak the colours):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Background="Yellow" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Background="Orange" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Background="Yellow" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Background="Yellow" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Background="Orange" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
               Source="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
            I am nice text spanning the whole row! Look, here's a lot
            of me in the cell.
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```